# main.py throws "ImportError: No module named app"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a file in the root directory of my app called main.py. This file contains the code which starts up the app:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes = routes, debug = True, config = config)

def main():
  app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I have, amongst others, this in app.yaml:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

After upgrading to the 1.6.6 SDK, I get the following error:

```
ERROR    2012-06-05 13:39:01,856 wsgi.py:189] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jdoe/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/Users/jdoe/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 236, in _LoadHandler
__import__(cumulative_path)
ImportError: No module named app
```

If I rename main.py to anything else than main.py and update app.yaml accordingly, this error disappears, and I can run the app.

Why can I no longer have my main routines in a file called main.py? On the App Engine SDK download page they say they're now including an experimental version of Python 2.7 in the SDK, could this have something to do with the issue I'm experiencing?

Comment: Solved this myself. In the same dir where main.py resides I had created a package also called main. In app.yaml, I'd specified to look in main.app. Seems that if a package called main exists in the same dir as main.py, Python goes to look inside the package for a module called app. But if no package named main exists, it happily looks in main.py.

Comment: That's down to Python, not App Engine - you can't have a package and a module by the same name. You should post your insight as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @akindo, please add your findings as an answer so they are easier to find!

Answer (score 0):

My comment as an answer:

Solved this myself. In the same dir where main.py resides I had created a package also called main. In app.yaml, I'd specified to look in main.app. Seems that if a package called main exists in the same dir as main.py, Python goes to look inside the package for a module called app. But if no package named main exists, it happily looks in main.py.